# Angular - Function in ControllerAs can not be executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, modal-dialog

I am new to Angular and would like to use Modal (Popup form) using `ui-bootstrap` from Angular. I am learning from [Angular bootstrap site](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/). It can be seen that it utilizes `ControllerAs` to control the popup.

The problem I face is the function in the ctrl cannot be executed in `ng-click` event, even though I already put the right value `ng-click='ctrl.open()'`

To make it clearer, I will provide my code below.

**Controller.js**

```
'use strict';

function funcListEmployeeCtrl($scope) {
    var ctrl = this;
    ctrl.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];
    ctrl.animationsEnabled = false;
    console.log(ctrl);
    ctrl.open = function (size, parentSelector) {
        console.log('selected'); //this is not fired
        var parentElem = parentSelector ? 
          angular.element($document[0].querySelector('.change-password-modal-container ' + parentSelector)) : undefined;
    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        animation: ctrl.animationsEnabled,
        ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-title',
        ariaDescribedBy: 'modal-body',
        templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
        controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'ctrl',
        size: size,
        appendTo: parentElem,
        resolve: {
            items: function () {
                return ctrl.items;
            }
        }
    });
}

angular.module('listEmployee')
    .controller('listEmployeeCtrl', ['$scope', funcListEmployeeCtrl])
    .controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($uibModalInstance, items) {
        var ctrl = this;
        ctrl.items = items;
        ctrl.selected = {
            item: $ctrl.items[0]
        };

      ctrl.ok = function () {
          $uibModalInstance.close($ctrl.selected.item);
      };

      ctrl.cancel = function () {
          $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
      };
});
```

Note that even the `console.log('selected');` is not fired. Therefore, it can be concluded that the function is not accessible by `ng-click`.

**View.html**

```
...
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="emp in data.employees|orderBy:orderByField:reverseSort|filter:{ Name: search_value }">
        <td>{{emp.SalesmanId}}</td>
        <td>{{emp.Name}}</td>
        <td>{{emp.Address}}</td>
        <td>{{emp.Phone}}</td>
        <td>{{emp.Email}}</td>
        <td ng-click='ctrl.open()'>{{emp.Username}}</td>
        <td>{{emp.Role}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
...
```

What I am trying to do is open a modal whenever the user clicks username cell. The HTML is working fine because I have tried changing `ng-click` to a function in `$scope` and it is working. Also, the `console.log(ctrl);` shows the content, so I am sure the ctrl object is set. Below I provide the screenshot of the log.

[image: ctrl object]

Note that I got DevTools warning from Chrome, I do not sure how to get rid of it (I use `.min.js` and not `.map`). However, I do not think that is the problem.
[image]

I am not sure where I went wrong. Any helps and guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: when you are able to access "data.employees" without preceding "ctrl" then it means you can access "open" also without preceding "ctrl". Can you try?

Comment: Can you show us where you use controllerAs?

Comment: @GiovaniVercauteren sure, it is when I initialize `modalInstance` I will update my question.

Comment: @ImmanuelKirubaharanS you mean putting `open` in the `$scope`?

Comment: Nope. I mean try changing "ctrl.open" into "open" in ng-click of your template.

Comment: @ImmanuelKirubaharanS already tried that and not working

Comment: you are using controllerAs in html templates like **ng-controller="listEmployeeCtrl as ctrl"** right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to confuse your current controller with the modalController. You declare `controllerAs: 'ctrl'` for you modal, but that doesn't mean you can use `ctrl` in your current controller.

You have two controllers, `listEmployeeCtrl` and `ModalInstanceCtrl`. Only the second controller (`ModalInstanceCtrl`) can use `ctrl` in its template.

If you want to use `ctrl` for `listEmployeeCtrl` as well you'll need to add the `ng-controller` directive to the view.html.

Using your sample code:

```
<div ng-controller="listEmployeeCtrl as ctrl">
    ...
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="emp in data.employees|orderBy:orderByField:reverseSort|filter:{ Name: search_value }">
            <td>{{emp.SalesmanId}}</td>
            <td>{{emp.Name}}</td>
            <td>{{emp.Address}}</td>
            <td>{{emp.Phone}}</td>
            <td>{{emp.Email}}</td>
            <td ng-click='ctrl.open()'>{{emp.Username}}</td>
            <td>{{emp.Role}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    ...
</div>
```

**OR**

where you describe your route you probably have something along the lines of

```
.when('...', {
    controller: 'listEmployeeCtrl',
    templateUrl: '.../view.html'
})
```

there you can add the controllerAs syntax:

```
.when('...', {
    controller: 'listEmployeeCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'ctrl',
    templateUrl: '.../view.html'
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! What is the difference between define the controller via routing `controller: ` and on the html element, i.e. `ng-controller="listEmployeeCtrl"`?

Comment: the ngController syntax allows you to easy add child controllers, while using routing syntax doesn't. Functionally, there's no difference.

Comment: Yeah, you are right! The function can be accessed now. Just need to fix the modal to get it working. Thank you for the explanation and your time for lending a hand!

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the modal id to get it open, which is missing!

Comment: Thanks for responding! Where should I put it? Note that even the `console.log('selected');` is not fired. I will update adding that info.

Comment: You are using template url, but had not defined in .cshtml.

Comment: use <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html"> above the tbody in .cshtml file

Comment: The table is not the modal template. I have my own template which already has that heading, but I do not write it here.